# Easy way to copy output from Jupyter to paste in Excel

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to find a simple way to change the standard output that I get in Jupyter in order to copy and paste tables ouputs in Excel.

For example a simple value_counts() give this kind of output in Jupyter lab/notebook:

0    1030971

1       8766

Is there a simple way to mark, copy and paste keeping the format? Even better, could the table have borders?

PD. I do not need to export results to excel, I only need to copy a few tables of all my output. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming your DataFrame is named "df", run this line and you'll save the data to your clipboard, letting you paste it where you need to.

```
df.to_clipboard(excel=True)
```

Comment: Not exactly what I imagined it, but it works! Thanks!

Comment: NB: You need to use the test import wizard and select Tab as the delimiter to actually load it up in Excel.

Comment: I never thought I would find myself here, but this answer is amazing and works when simply highlighting your table and copying+pasting will sometimes not work...